# How Can We Create A Line Renderer That Moves According To Joystick In Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, joystick, aim

I am trying to create a **Brawl Stars** clone for fun purposes. I created all other mechanics but there's one which i can't seem to figure out.

I am trying to create an Aim Bar which will let player know which direction he is currently aiming at...

Also i want this effect to only be visible when player is either moving the aim joystick or holding the aim joystick.

How can we create a *Line Renderer* in unity which rotates depending upon the joystic's current rotation. I want to achieve a similar effect to how **Brawl Stars** does with its aim bar

I am using **Free Joystick Pack** from unity asset store

Link to Joystick pack -> https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631

Here is an image of how i want the effect to be...

[image]